# Color overlay over button with image background in Android

Tags: android

I have a layout which contains a button and a text view. I want to apply a color (with some alpha) to that layout. I've already tried many solutions other suggested and I ended up with this:

```
<!-- Header -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/header_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:background="@color/app_dark_gray">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background_image"
        android:text=""
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textinfobar"
        style="@style/InfoBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:text="" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#DD000000"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I appended a `View` to my relative layout and gave it the color  I wanted.

**The problem** is that only the `TextView` gets that color. The button stays the same way. Is there any way I can solve this?

EDIT:

I need this to work on API 16 and higher

Comment: set `android:translationZ="2dp"` to your overlay view. The `translationZ` value has to be greater than 1dp

Comment: Can you share us the code you using to set the Button background color

Comment: @d.gjinovci That would work but its only for API level 21 and higher. I should have mentioned that I want API 16+

Comment: @Kunu The button has a background image `android:background="@drawable/button_background_image"`

Comment: If you just want the alpha then you can set the alpha in Button. And if you are creating the drawable in xml then set the alpha for the background.

Comment: You should show us a demo image which you want to achieve.